# Understanding the constructor attribute in Polymer elements

Tags: polymer

A Polymer noob...

I'm trying to create a custom element as per the Polymer API docs, where my main page looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Polymer</title>
    <script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <polymer-element name="book-template" constructor="BookTemplate" noscript>
      <template>
        <style>
          h1 { color: orange; }
        </style>

        <h1>Hello from some-foo</h1>

      </template>
    </polymer-element>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know that the page content will render if I just put `<book-template></book-template>` on the page, or if I do something like this inside the `<body>` tag:

```
  <script>
    var book = document.createElement('book-template');
    document.getElementById('test').appendChild(book);
  </script>
```

But I'm trying to utilize the element's constructor attribute, assuming that this will create the element when placed somewhere inside of `<body>`:

```
<script>
  var book = new BookTemplate();
</script>
```

...but getting a console message that BookTemplate() is not defined.

I'm sure it's something simple...any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you have to wait for the [polymer-ready event](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#polymer-ready), so that the constructor is available in the global `window` object http://jsbin.com/kosuf/2/edit?html,console,output:

```js
<script>
  document.addEventListener('polymer-ready',function() {
  var book = new BookTemplate();  
    if (book) {
      console.log('Ok');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Is this in the docs somewhere? The only thing I see about this is here: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#attributes